# Delphi Android pass variables to a Service

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

So I have a basic Android service created, which currently does nothing, but I need to pass info to the Android service from my main Delphi project for example : Name,   ID etc.

So I could use in the service, for example there would be a function which every 10 minutes logs stuff, eg. 'John (2514) Tried to do something silly'

I need to do it in a Android Service, because it always runs, either the app is opened or closed.

NOTE: This app is used on a company device, for work purposes, and this information is needed.

Comment: Note that Android services are sometimes force-stopped by the system and should be designed to gracefully handle a restart - https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Comment: Watch this video. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A59ymC3fL-0)